# Can you set page attributes via HTTP POST to page object?

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-page

With most objects documented in the Graph API, you can POST to the API to set attributes of the object. I'm trying to do this with a Page object.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

I have a proper page access token.

Using the OAuth2 gem in Ruby:

```
params = Hash.new
params['about'] = "All about my page ..."
token.post( "/#{page_id}", params )
```

No matter which field I specify, I always get this error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Parameters do not match any fields that can be updated","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.  The OAuth2 gem ain't the same as the OAuth gem, even thought they are similar.  (I had cut and pasted code from a Twitter update_profile.json call using the OAuth gem.)

The OAuth2 gem's post method takes HTTP parameters as a hash in a 'body' element in the options hash.

This works:

```
params = Hash.new
params['about'] = "All about my page ..."
token.post( "/#{page_id}", { :body => params } )
```